# Problems with react-table using "useSortBy"

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-usememo

I am having some problems on react-table using `useSortBy`. With no `useSortBy` the table works fine.
Getting this error:

**Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.**

```
var COLUMNS = [
    {
        Header: 'Data Criação',
        accessor: 'createdAt',
        Cell: ({value})=> {return value ? format(new Date(value),  'dd/MM/yyyy') : ''},
    },
    {
        Header: 'Nome',
        accessor: 'name'
    },
    {
        Header: 'Telefone',
        accessor: 'mobile'
    },
    {
        Header: 'Email',
        accessor: 'email'
    },
    {
        Header: 'Action',
        accessor: (hit)=>{
            return <LeadTableAction item={hit} selection={handleLeadDataSelection}/>
        }
    }
]

const columns = useMemo(()=>COLUMNS, []);

const tableInst = useTable({
    columns,
    data:props.lead.leadData ? props.lead.leadData : [{}]
}, useSortBy);

const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
} = tableInst;
```

On JSX:

```
<Table {...getTableProps()}>
    <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(hg=>{
           return (
               <tr {...hg.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                   {hg.headers.map(h=>{
                   return (
                           <th {...h.getHeaderProps(h.getSortByToggleProps())}>
                              {h.render("Header")}
                                <span style={{marginLeft: '5px'}}>
                              {h.isSorted ? (h.isSortedDesc ? <i className="fas fa-sort-down"></i> : <i className="fas fa-sort-up"></i>) : ''}
                              </span>
                           </th>
                           )
                    })}
              </tr>
              )
         })}
  </thead>
  <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
     {rows.map(row=>{
        prepareRow(row)
        return(
           <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
               {row.cells.map(cell=>{
               return(
                 <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                     {cell.render('Cell')}
                 </td>
                     )
               })}
          </tr>
          )
     })}
  </tbody>
```

Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved,

I just add a memo in my code:

```
const data = useMemo(()=>{
    return props.lead.leadData ? props.lead.leadData : [{}]
}, [props.lead.leadData]);
```

This props.lead is the data to fetch direct on the table.
Done! :)

Answer (score 0):

The whole time I tried passing an empty dependency array and my code did not throw any error there. It showed me errors only where I used hooks. I passed the data in the dependency hook in the `useMemo` array and it worked.

```
const data = useMemo(() => (employees.data), [employees.data]);
```